# Call Windows Calculator c#

Tags: c#, windows, calculator

I use

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc");`

It works well on localhost, but when the project is deployed and I access the website and call the calculator, it does not work, nothing literally happens. No errors or so.

I expect the calculator to launch on the client machine. How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to happen here. Were you expecting the calculator to launch on the client machine or on the server?

Comment: You need to open Calc in client machine, right? . How it possible by using a server code.The process may be already started on the server where u hosted it

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm expecting the calculator to launch in the client machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launching a process directly from  a website is disallowed from the browser for security reasons. You need to write a browser plugin to perform this operation.

Comment: What really, that makes sense. Is there any other work around?

Comment: By the way, thanks for the clarification, and for the suggestion of a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Please try some client side code.
Something like below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        function launchExecutable() {
            var shellActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

            shellActiveXObject.Run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe", 1, false);
            shellActiveXObject = null;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="launchExecutable();" value="button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Code not tested. Hope this may help you

Comment: Hi this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712237/to-access-notepad-calculator-through-asp-net shows it also can't be done. Anyways thanks! It never came through my mind calling it using javascript.